# How to compare 2 build configurations of visual studio 2010 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, projects-and-solutions, buildconfiguration

I have a huge solution in Visual Studio 2010 (more then 30 F# and C# projects). Just now I get a problem with building of solution in different configurations (say, Release|AnyCPU and Debug|AnyCPU). Seems, that problem is in target platform differences. Is it possible to extract and compare build configurations for solution (as XML, plain text)? In configuration manager window not all information is provided.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [MSBuildEmitSolution](http://threeisit.com/post/MSBuildEmitSolution.aspx) and compare intermediate project files generated, then up verbosity to [diagnostic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx) and pipe out logs via [fileLogger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171470.aspx) or [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) and compare with a [diff tool](http://winmerge.org/) or just [step through it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx) directly.

Comment: True enough, but i bet its just a reference that has been linked to from a bin\debug folder, like it normally always is.